# Find and Replace first character after a certain pattern

Tags: regex, sed

Current text

```
Variable length text = some string(some more text
```

Change to

```
Variable length text = some string(addition some more text
```

Need to add a certain text after first parenthesis in a line only after "=" character is encountered. Another condition is to ignore patterns like "= (", which essentially means you should ignore patterns with only space between "=" and "("

My Try:

```
sed -e "s#*=(\w\()#\1(addition#g"
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak this for your needs:

```
$ echo 'Variable length text = some string(some more text' |\
sed 's/^[^=]*=[^(]*[[:alnum:]][^(]*(/&addition /'
```

That matches for:

1. Beginning of the string
2. Anything but `=` any number of times
3. `=`
4. Anything but `(` any number of times
5. An alpha-numeric character
6. Anything but `(` any number of times
7. `(`

... and substitutes it with the matched string adding `' addition'` to it.
The output is

```
Variable length text = some string(addition some more text
```

Answer (score 1):

in perl

```
s/(.*?=[\s][^(]+?)\((.*)/$1(aditional text $2/
```